# Android BroadcastReceiver is never called

Tags: android, broadcast

Hi all and thank you for your help!
I'll start with the code
So, the class with the broadcast receiver is this:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    // ...
    // ACTION
    public static final String action = "com.mywebsite.myapp.package.class.action";
    // ...
    public void onCreate() {
        // SET BROADCAST RECEIVER
        broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                Log.w("broadcast receiver", "action: " + action);
                if (action.equals("**")) {
                    Log.w("broadcast receiver", "**");
                }
            }
        };
        // REGISTER BROADCAST
        final IntentFilter myFilter = new IntentFilter();
        myFilter.addAction(action);
        registerReceiver(this.broadcastReceiver, myFilter);
    }
    // ....
}
```

And I try to send a broadcast in this way from a fragment

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity()
        .getApplicationContext(), MediaPlayerService.class);
getActivity().startService(myIntent);
myIntent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
        MediaPlayerService.class);
myIntent.setAction(MyService.action);
myIntent.putExtra("data", "*******");
getActivity().sendBroadcast(myIntent);
```

However the broadcast receiver is never called. I can say this because of the logcat: the line Log.w("broadcast receiver", "action: " + action); is never called. How can I resolve?

Thank you!

EDIT: class code:

```
public class MediaPlayerService extends Service {

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;
    private AudioManager audioManager;
    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;
    private String absoluteFilePath;
    private Boolean areThereAnyErrors = false;
    private int savedVolume;
    // ACTIONS
    public static final String prepareAndPlayNewFile = "com.disgustingapps.player.AudioManagement.MediaPlayerService.prepareAndPlayNewFile";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.w("MediaPlayerService", "onCreate called");
        // SET BROADCAST RECEIVER
        broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                Log.w("broadcast receiver", "action: " + action);
                if (action.equals("prepareAndPlayNewFile")) {
                    Log.w("broadcast receiver", "prepareAndPlayNewFile");
                    prepareAndPlayNewFile(intent
                            .getStringExtra("absoluteFilePath"));
                }
            }
        };
        // REGISTER BROADCAST
        final IntentFilter myFilter = new IntentFilter();
        myFilter.addAction(prepareAndPlayNewFile);
        registerReceiver(this.broadcastReceiver, myFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.w("MediaPlayerService", "onDestroy called");
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.w("MediaPlayerService", "onStartCommand called");
        // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
        // stopped, so return sticky.
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public void prepareAndPlayNewFile(String absoluteFilePath) {
        // ...do something...
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you confirmed your service is running when you try to send the broadcast? I would guess that the service has not registered the BroadcastReceiver before you send the broadcast.

Comment: Agreed with @Bobbake4. Add some extra logging to your `Service` to show it registering the receiver and add some to the `Fragment` to show it sending the broadcast.

Comment: I checked both and they run! So what can be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are not receiving the `Intent` is because the receiver is in `onCreate()`.
`context.startService()` will only pass the `Activity`'s `Intent` to the `Service`'s `onStartCommand()`. The `Service` has already been created by then (or should have), so trying to receive in `onCreate()` will never work.

More info [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle)

Trying to receive in `onStartCommand()` will only work once (guess). But having a `BroadcastReceiver` in `onStartCommand` will only get you the data if you call `startService()`. Since you are calling this anyway, it's far easier just do ditch the `BroadcastReceiver` and just pass the data with the `Intent` delivered to the `Service`s `onStartCommand()`.

**EDIT**

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.w("MediaPlayerService", "onCreate called");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.w("MediaPlayerService", "onDestroy called");
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.w("MediaPlayerService", "onStartCommand called");     

    String action = intent.getAction();
    Log.w("onStartCommand()", "action: " + action);

    if (action.equals("prepareAndPlayNewFile")) {
       prepareAndPlayNewFile(intent.getStringExtra("absoluteFilePath"));
    }

    // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
    // stopped, so return sticky.   
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Then just do this:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), MediaPlayerService.class);
myIntent.setAction("prepareAndPlayNewFile");
myIntent.putExtra("absoluteFilePath", "/path/");
startService(myIntent);
```

[`startService()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService%28android.content.Intent%29):

> Every call to this method will result in a corresponding call to the target service's onStartCommand(Intent, int, int) method, with the intent given here. This provides a convenient way to submit jobs to a service without having to bind and call on to its interface.

Comment: I tried But doesn't work.. Maybe because I need to receive broadcast after the service has been started, while the service is running. Could be this the reason? Thank you

Comment: But at this Point why use broadcast?

Comment: ah I see what you mean. Wait, I'll try something

Comment: or just pass the data with the `Intent` delivered with `onStartCommand()`, you are calling this anyway, so why make it complicated? Edited my answer accordingly :)

Comment: But I need to send info to the service while it is running not to start it again and again :D

Comment: it doesn't matter, you won't notice the difference. If you insist on using a receiver, you have to make a seperate class for it and point to that with `registerReceiver()`, like already mentioned.

Comment: Oh my God it works! Thank you for your help! I really appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the code for the service and how its started its hard to tell where the issue is..

First, you're registering the receiver in the onCreate of the service but you dont have an unregister event.. You should put the broadcast receiver in the global scope of your service class and unregister in onDestroy() (Override onDestroy and log a message to confirm its stopping)

Second unless you bind to the service then the service will "Stop" as soon as the commands in the startup execute.

You should override onStartCommand and return START_STICKY to keep the service running.

Comment: It returns START_STICKY!
I edit my first post with the code of the part of the class concerning the problem. Hope you can help me! And thank you a lot in advance:)